# How to run react native android project with offline gradle?

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

I develop react native android project and in order to build and run my project, I use  `react-native run-android` command.

When we build in android studio, we can build our project with offline mode gradle settings.

Is there a command that runs react native android project with offline gradle? Is there any other solution for building react native android project with offline gradle.

Note: I know to can build and run the project from android studio with offline gradle but I'm looking for a solution that runs react native andorid project without opening android studio.

Comment: Sounds familiar! Like me looking for economic usage of react native because of poor and expensive internet connection :)) . I'll tell u if find a way, but how about u? find anything?

Comment: No, I don't find any way thanks @KhalilLaleh